# Is Goddess Kali ever represented in the form of a child?

Tags: goddess, devi, kali, devi-bhagavata-purana, dasha-mahavidya

We know that Goddess Parvati is worshiped in her child or Kumari form and in north India Kanya-pujan is done at the end of Navratri as a symbolic offering to the goddess. To some extent the Brahmacharini form of Nav Durga and Bal Tripura Sundari also show the goddess as an unmarried girl. But do we have any such mention in any scripture of **Goddess Kali as a child or a young girl?**

Comment: BTW Goddess Kali also likes the act of worshipping Kumaris. But you seem to be asking a different Q.

Comment: There is a laghusyamala form.

Comment: At least there is a story where Lord Shiva becomes child to pacify angry Kali...

Comment: @Tezz ya i know that. The question is for Kali being depicted as a child.

Comment: @Rickross yes the question is different.

Comment: @moonstar2001 any scriptural references for that?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Goddess Kali and Goddess Shyamala are different deities.

Comment: @Rickross I am aware of that just asking out of curiosity. SInce I am not sure the word laghu actually refers to Bala Shyamala

Comment: Yes you are right Laghu does not always refer to child form. Example Laghu navaavarana, laghu shodasha nyasa, laghu pranapratishta etc..@Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: Laghu means small or condensed form.of mantra.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is a Bala form of Bhadrakali (and not Kali).

Her description is found in Kerala Agams. Mostly Bhadrakali temples in Kerala worship her in Bala form as in that way it is easy to control her rage.

Her iconography in Kerala tantras is as follows-

> Sitting in padmasana, the devi is adorned with anklets in feet. She has huge fang and yet sports a smile of a child. The mundamala adorns her neck, with moon as her diadem on her crown. Know the Dhala and Chakra to be in her upper left & right hands, and Kapala and Khadga in her lower Left and righht hands respectively as her Ayudhas.

[image]

**Vigraha of Bala Bhadrakali**

Some of the notable temples of Bala Bhadrakali are -

Pournami Kavu, Venganoor, Kerala
Erumpili, Kanyakumari, TN
Melparai, Eraniel, TN
Kaipuram pattanam, Kerala
Shri Bala Bhadrakali Kshetram,  Perumkadavila, Kerala
Bhadrakali Kavu, Palakkad

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: Very nice, thanks for sharing. Do share any reference from the scriptures if you have.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal I have no referance other than this dhyan mantra given here. The idol you saw is of one of the Bala Bhadrakali sadhaka from Kerala. He didn't revealed much about her. Yet, if I get to know about her will update.